# blank apache log requests

Tags: apache, logging, ddos

We have a site that appears to get DDOS'ed periodically. When this happens we get hundreds of requests that are basically blank like below in the domain's access log. They are all exactly the same except for the time stamp.

```
54.236.211.114 - - [20/Apr/2015:22:31:11 +0000] "GET /404.php HTTP/1.0" 404 469 "-" "-"
```

The IP address listed is the server's IP address (its doing an internal request to get the 404 page), but beyond that we are not seeing anything as to who is doing this, what url they are trying access etc.

My questions is, is there a way to determine where this attack is coming from and what URL they are trying to access, possibly from a different log file or something?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual URL is "/404.php".  They could just be requesting a fake page in order to overload your server. You can block this guy in iptables or your htaccess file. Here's what you'd put in htaccess.

```
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from 54.236.211.114
```

Answer (score 0):

We were able to change how the requests were being handled in the cms, it appears that all of the pages that were causing problems were similar to this: domain.com/www.someotherdomain

So we instead routed all requests for /www.something to die before the page rendered.